# Removing Places from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, places, leaflet

Doe is exists a way to remove all the places from the OSM map? Also like shops, bars, restorations, hotels etc.

I wish to use a maps with a less info. Is it possible to do this from the original OSM server? Maybe like a option in URL or something else? I use Leaflet library for my project, maybe some option in it?

Comment: Im looking for the same, have you found a solution ?. please :(
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but here's a couple ideas:

If you only want tiles for a background layer, there are some different tile options listed here (some of which have fewer labels): http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles

If you want to download only certain data, this page gives you a start on how to do so: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Comment: I wished to have it like in GMAPS API:

 `new google.maps.Map(map_div,{
  styles:[{
   elementType:'all',
   featureType:'poi',
   stylers:[{
    visibility:'off'
    }]
   }]});`

Over JS or over extra URL, so or so, but without places.